# Determining what happened to a file

Tags: windows-xp

I just got back from vacation, and I had left my laptop locked. When I returned the laptop had rebooted, and I had to log back in.

When I did, I noticed that a file that I use a lot (my KeePass database file) was missing. I have no idea where it went, or how. I did not notice any other files missing.

I had a backup of the file (Thank you JungleDisk/EC2) but I am just curious as to what happened. Should I be worried about hard drive corruption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likelyhood of your filetable corrupting and losing only one file is very low - I'd be more worried about somebody else gaining access to your laptop. No real need to worry about security, assuming you have a good password, I don't believe KeyPass' encryption is particularly vulnerable.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this, but it seems unlikely. I mean if someone wanted the file, why would they delete it. 

The reason I asked about how to see what happened is there is a slight chance that I accidentally moved the file, or deleted it. But I'm not certain.

Comment: If you think you may have, try a search engine, like `Everything`(which has a portable edition), which should find it if it is, indeed, anywhere still on your HDD.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Phoshi regarding only a single file being gone.  Not likely to be filetable corruption in that case.

Look in your System and Security Event Logs (Control Panel | Computer Management | expand Event Logs) for events during the time you were gong corresponding to system shutdown and login/logout events.  This might give you some insight whether or not someone did something like forcefully logged you out, who rebooted, etc.

It doesn't sound like it, but was your laptop powered back on or was it shutdown?  If it was shutdown it could be a power failure.  I've seen all kinds of messed up things happen.

Also, have you done a full search on your drive for the file?  Maybe it got moved.